# How to get more zoom from mupdf

Tags: android, mupdf

I have implemented mupdf for my android application.It is working fine,but i need more zoom.I tried to override onDoubleTap method,but it didn't worked.How to implement more zoom facility?

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure, but i think the field "mScale = 1.0f" in ReaderView.java is the key. 
For a quick test, increase it a bit and see what happens, e.g. to 1.2f